# How to change the default location of Evolution mail folder to another device

Tags: evolution

I have two HDD.

1. dev/sdb : 74 gb
2. dev/sda : 500 gb

The boot loader is in sdb. Now the problem is due to heavy emails in evolution, the drive is overloaded and throwing error of low disk space.

I have to either shift the evolution mail folder or the boothloader to sda to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Evolution Data Storage: https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.20/data-storage.html.en

The user's data files

```
$HOME/.local/share/evolution
```

Various configuration and state files

```
$HOME/.config/evolution
```

Account settings

```
$HOME/.config/evolution/sources
```

Disposable data caches

```
$HOME/.cache/evolution
```

Configuration settings in GSettings

```
$HOME/.config/dconf
```

You could move your data and use Symlinks on those directories

```
ln -s /path_to_evolution_Data /path_to_symlink
```

example:

```
mv $HOME/.local/share/evolution /mnt/DATA/email/
ln -s /mnt/DATA/email/evolution $HOME/.local/share/evolution
```

Where /mnt/DATA must be a filesystem on yout big Drive */dev/sda*

Answer (score 0):

create a directory in the new drive and give your user permission to write to that directory.

Copy your evolution mail directory over to that new drive/directory.  Then remove it from it's original location.  Finally create a symlink from the new location to the old location.

I don't know exactly where evolution stores it's mail by default.  But the general sequence of events using Thunderbird (another email program) would look something like this:

```
$sudo mkdir /new/drive/myuser
$sudo chown myuser:myuser /new/drive/myuser
$cd /home/myuser
$cp -r .thunderbird /new/drive/myuser
$rm -rf .thunderbird
$ln -s /new/drive/myuser/.thunderbird .thunderbird
```

Answer (score 0):

For the change destination folder your email you may do this:
example:

```
new_path = your path to new email folder !
old_path = your path to oryginal path evolution like this /home/your_home_name/.local/share/
```

1) Move your existing evolution folder to the new folder

```
mv /home/your_home_name/.local/share/evolution /new_path/
```

2) Remove folder evolution from `/home/your_home_name/.local/share/`   if exist !

3) Make link to the new location evolution folder

```
ln -s /new_path/evolution /home/your_home_name/.local/share/
```

Remember, when you make link path the folder ../evolution in .local/share/ cannot exist in this location!

> In FEDORA Evolution have data in .cache/evolution/  !!!

4) Move your existing evolution folder `.cache/evolution` to the new folder

```
mv /home/your_home_name/.cache/evolution /new_path/
```

5) `ln -s /new_destination(new_path)/cache/evolution/ /home/your_name/.cache/evolution`
Remember folder evolution cannot exist! Remove it first!

6) Try to run Evolution